# Why Django dont let me do email=models.ManyToManyField(models.EmailField)?

Tags: django-models

I mean if i have a model Contact that can have multiples emails is logic that i reuse models and reuse EmailField and i make:

class contact(models.Model):
               emails=models.ManyToManyField(models.EmailField)

Answer (score 0):

Relation fields can only connect to other models. Create a separate model to hold email addresses.

Comment: But EmailField conect then with some class email, that has all methods implemented for email. Also, if i want make a Field that has manytomany with a Relation Field? This is correct too...

Comment: You cannot create a relation to a field object. Period. Stop trying.

Comment: of Course i can not. I just say that. I want know why? If Django make that restricction with some objetive or just because they dont think in this posiblity. And please dont be rude.

Comment: Django's ORM can't do anything that the underlying database can't.

Comment: Thank you. But for me this is not a reason is just a fact.